# EWS C# - Null FileName returned

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices

I am using EWS to retrieve attachments. However in some cases the attachment file name is not returned correctly.

If I use the Name property of FileAttachment I get a value which is incorrect, i.e it differs from what I can see in Outlook. If I use the FileName property of FileAttachment then the value of FileName is null.

I note that another person has posted a similar problem but there were no solutions given.

Does anyone know a workaround for this problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What type of attachment are you working with? if they are an attached messages then a blank filename would be expected. You can't request extended properties on attachments so generally you have to work with what you get returned in the GetAttachment Request. You might want to have a look at the one of the attachments in question with a MAPI editor like MFCMapi that will give you visibility of the properties on the attachments and you can generally determine what is being returned.

Cheers
Glen

Comment: Thanks Glen. They are file attachments. The name property displays correctly but the filename always appears as null.

Comment: I have taken a look using MFCMapi and the issue seems to be that FileAttachment.Name is being set to PR_DISPLAY_NAME by EWS where as I am interested in PR_ATTACH_LONG_FILENAME.

Comment: Unfortunately there is no solution for that you have to deal with what you get returned because EWS doesn't allow you to access Extended properties on Attachments (or the recipients collection)